# WP All Imports is modifying all my variations

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

I'm importing products with WP All Import. I have a column in the CSV that, if it's set to "yes", it adds a custom term. If is set to "no", it removes the custom term. I add/remove the term using the hook `pmxi_saved_post`. The catch is that if it's a variable product, and some of their children have the term, the parent must have the term. If none of the children have it, I must remove the term from the parent.

It works fine in every case except when I remove the term on one (or more than one but less than total children) of the children. In that case what it does? It removes the term from ALL children and keeps the term on the parent.

Same code is used in the WP Admin Dashboard to add or remove the term and it works ok. So may be WP All Imports does some strange thing with variations. Any idea what can I try?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code?